# Transcoding FLV to MP4 with ffmpeg very slow

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to support the recording of webcam video on our website, which I then need to transcode to MP4 and WebM to support HTML5 playback. I have ffmpeg 1.2 installed on our server, and have the whole process running fairly well.

The one problem I do have though is transcoding FLV to MP4. it is unacceptably slow, e.g. an 8 second FLV takes about 2.5 mins to transcode!

The `ffmpeg` command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i webcam.flv -c:a libfaac -ac 2 -b:a 64k -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 \
  -b:v 350k webcam.mp4
```

There are so many `ffmpeg` params, I am a bit lost as to the best way forward with this issue. You can download a test flv from here:

[`dropbox.com/s/hhd6uhdiuhk800w/webcam.flv`](http://dropbox.com/s/hhd6uhdiuhk800w/webcam.flv)

By comparison, transcoding to WebM takes about 5 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y -i webcam.flv -c:a libvorbis -ac 2 -b:a 64k -ar 44100 -c:v libvpx \
  -b:v 350k -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 webcam.webm
```

Comment: It takes around 6 seconds for me on a Quad Core i7 MacBook Pro. What happens when you add `-preset superfast` after `-c:v libx264`? Note that this will usually reduce compression efficiency. Please supply the full, uncut console output for the commands as well and give us some info about your hardware.

Comment: thx foryour reply @slhck, it made me go back and look closer at the ffmpeg output, which in turn gave me the clue for the solution. cheers.

Answer (score 4):

ok i found the answer. i had a closer look at the ffmpeg output, and noticed:

```
[mp4 @ 0xa0060c0] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
```

doh. so i added "-vsync 2" as the last parameter before the output file and it worked a charm, took transcoding time down to about 10 secs! very happy.

working out "generalised" ffmpeg settings for all types of a/v input still seems like black magic to me...